# Allow single digit and double digits range using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, range

With below regex pattern, following number range are match or not match which is fine as expected. The only issue I am having is when I have range as 2-10 or 8-12 (single digit to double digit) then this pattern is not match

Examples

1 match

1-2 match

-2 not match

1, 2-3, 4, 5-7 match

1 2, 3 not match

1-2-2 not match

10-15 match

**2-10 not match** //this should be match but not matching with below pattern

`var patt1 = new RegExp("^(\\s*\\d+\\s*\\-\\s*\\d+\\s*,?|\\s*\\d+\\s*,?)+$");`

Comment: This [works fine](https://repl.it/Bwlv/0) when I test it. Please clarify the exact string you are testing against.

Comment: Might be that \\- that's causing the issue, \- is not valid.  You could write this as var patt1 = /^(\s*\d+\s*\-\s*\d+\s*,?|\s*\d+\s*,?)+$/;

Comment: Your pattern works for me using "2-10" as well.  As does /^(\s*\d+\s*-\s*\d+\s*,?|\s*\d+\s*,?)+$/ and /^(\s*\d+\s*\-\s*\d+\s*,?|\s*\d+\s*,?)+$/

Comment: @GregL yes you are right the pattern should work, I found another issue where I am checking for two string value "2" > "10" which is failing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
^((?:\d+(?:-\d+)*)(?:,\s(?:\d+(?:-\d+)*))*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ6uJ0/1)

Input

```
1
1-2
-2
1, 2-3, 4, 5-7
1 2, 3
1-2-2
10-15
2-10
```

Output

```
MATCH 1
1.  `1`
MATCH 2
1.  `1-2`
MATCH 3
1.  `1, 2-3, 4, 5-7`
MATCH 4
1.  `1-2-2`
MATCH 5
1.  `10-15`
MATCH 6
1.  `2-10`
```